# CSS not working but <style> working Div with Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, divide

Formatting of Inner works in  tags on my HTML but does not work in a Linked CSS file. Not sure why!?

I have tried renaming classes and searching for solutions online but cant find anything that helps me.

```html
<div class="Inner">
<iframe src="Form.php" name="Inside" allowTransparency="false" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>
            
</div>
```

```css
.Inner {
    color: black;
    position:fixed;
    width: 900px;
    height:900px;
    left: 300px;
    top:100px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Im execting it to be 300px left and 100px top but this will only work when I wrap it in  tags on my HTML page but does not work on the linked CSS file (the CSS works for every other tag I.e Nav/Header.

## EDIT

Full CSS style file

```css
/*HTML 5 display rule*/
address, article, aside, canvas, content, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, menu, section, summary {
display:block
}

.Inner {
    color: black;
    position:fixed;
    width: 900px;
    height:900px;
    left: 300px;
    top:100px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, tr, th {
border: 1px solid black;
font-family:"League Spartan",Arial ;
}

h1{
    font-family:"League Spartan",Arial ;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #000000;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'League Spartan';
    src: url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.eot');
    src: url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('U:/Web Development/fonts/leaguespartan-bold.svg#league_spartanbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}



nav {   
    font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
    float:left;
    color:black;
    width: 300px;
    height:800px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#17499b;
    top: 100px;
    left:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;

    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000000 inset;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow:0px 5px 10px #000000 inset; /*safari*/
    
}
nav li{
        font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
    list-style-type:none;
}
nav ul li a{
        font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:10px;
    /* css3 transition */
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -o-transition-property:all;
    -o-transition-duration:.5s;
    -moz-transition-property:all;
    -moz-transition-duration:.5s;
    transition-property:all;
    transition-duration:.5s;

    border: .5px solid black;
    width:200px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 7.5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000; /*safari*/
    
}
nav li a:link{
    font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
        text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    
}
nav li a:visited{
    font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
        text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
}
nav li a:hover{
    font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#0800ff;
    background-color:#5b9819;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000 inset; /* safari */
}
nav li a:active{
    font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#000000;
}


header{
        font-family:League Spartan, Arial;
    line-height:25px;
    text-align :center;
    
    border:0px solid black;
    color:black;
    width:100%;
    height: var(--TitleHeight);
    background-color:  var(--maincolor);
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000000 inset;
}
```

Full HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title> RESOURCE FORGE </title>

<meta name="keywords" content="KEY WORD1, KEYWORD 2, KEY WORD3" />
<meta name="description" content ="Description for the website" />
<meta name="aurthor" content="Chris Livermore" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.CSS" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="Inner">
          
        <iframe src="Form.php" name="Inside" allowTransparency="false" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" width="100%" height="100%">
        </iframe>
            
    </div>
    
    <nav>
        <h2>NAVIGATION</h2>
        <h4>CHAPTER 1</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Form.php" target="Inside">USER INPUT</a> </li>
            <li><a href=# target="Inside"></a> </li>
            <li><a href="Contact_Form.php" target="Inside">Add New Contact</a> </li>
            <li><a href="phonelistFN.php" target="Inside">View Phone List</a> </li>
            <li><a href="easyinporter.php" target="Inside">EASY INPORTER</a> </li>
            <li><a href="C1 T6 - Images.html" target="Inside">T6 - Images</a> </li>
            <li><a href="C1 T7 - Tables.html" target="Inside">T7 - Tables</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>

        <h1>RESOURCE FORGE</h1>
        <p>This Site is currently under development- some features may be missing or partially completed </p>
    </header>

</body>


</html>
```

As you can see I'm using the nav bar to load new pages in the Inner div. cant understand why it wont it works fine in the style tags but not in the CSS file when everything else works fine?

Comment: Can you provide the full script or maybe a runable program (something like JSFiddle)? There is much that could go wrong. Is the CSS file loaded from your HTML page? Does clearing the cache help?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the Chrome Cache. Cleared it and the formatting worked.